# Excel Interop C# - 'Print Entire WorkBook'

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, excel-interop

I would like to know if it is possible to set the 'Print Entire WorkBook' setting in my C# application using Interop.

If it is not possible then any recommendations in how to replicate this would be useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you question is ***how to print*** the entire workbook then you can use the `Workbook.PrintOut` method.

For example, the following code will print one copy of the whole workbook on printer called "XEROX312":

```
this.PrintOut(1, false, "XEROX312", false, false, missing);
```

You can also set the start page, end page and number of copies in parameters 1, 2, 3, respectively.

For more information look in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.printout%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

> 

If you ask ***how to set the properties*** for the print entire workbook dialog, then I don't think you can set the programatically. I would suggest creating a custom GUI that will allow to set the parameters and you can then invoke the `PrintOut` method.